# Windows e Avast estão bloqueando a compilação de programas em C

Tags: c, dev-c++

Sempre que trabalhei com linguagem C, utilizava os computadores da faculdade, sendo assim, nunca tive problemas em compilá-los e executá-los na IDE Dev-C++. Atualmente, instalei em minha máquina a versão 5.11, mas só fui tentar utilizá-lo hoje. Para teste, escrevi um código bem básico, salvei e ao clicar em "Compilar e Executar", recebi um alerta que nunca havia me deparado antes:

cannot open output file (...)\testes.exe: Permission denied
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Junto ao erro, o Avast abre uma janela de navegação, informando:
"

### Acabamos de proteger seu arquivo

**Id.exe** está tentando alterar ou excluir o arquivo **TESTES.EXE** na sua pasta protegida **Documents**.

"

Qual seria o procedimento para conseguir compilar e executar os programas normalmente e, evitar que o antivirus leia-o antes de sua execução (pois isso tornaria o processo muito mais lento). ?

Comment: O Windows não faz nada. O AV faz mesmo, por isso eu não uso em máquina de desenvolvimento a não ser o Defender que não é tão intrusivo, mesmo assim faço exceção nas pastas que o compilador acessa. De qq forma seria melhor escolher um IDE melhor, esse é bem problemático.

Comment: Entendi. Qual vc me recomendaria?

Comment: Tem usado o Defender no Windows 10, até agora não encontrei problemas, e tem protegido bem.

Comment: @GuilhermePonsoniFerreira Visual Studio ou VS Code ou Code::Blocks, na verdade qualquer um menos o Dev-C++.

Answer (score -2):

Só ir no ícone do avast perto do relógio (canto inferior direito) > Clicar com o botão direito nele > Vai em “Controle dos Módulos do Avast” > E desabilita ele pelo tempo necessário.
Abraço!